# nmcli does not show available networks using USB adapter

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi, networkmanager, nmcli

I recently bought a TP-Link TL-WN823N wireless USB adapter and I cannot find any WiFi networks using nmcli. I am able to connect using Windows to my buildings network however running `nmcli dev wifi` lists no networks avaiable. The device is shown using `ip link`:

```
3: wlp3s0f0u4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
```

and with `nmcli`:

```
wlp3s0f0u4: disconnected
        "TP-Link TL-WN823N v2/v3"
        wifi (rtl8xxxu), B6:52:B0:C9:15:1A, hw, mtu 1500
```

However when I run `nmcli d wifi list` no networks appear. I have seen elsewhere that blacklisting rtl8xxxu could solve this however that also did not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated because this is driving me a bit crazy.

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/q/1194048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out and it was ridiculously simple, just needed to get a network connection to download the rtl8192 package and blacklist the rtl8xxxu driver as before.